# AVL Tree in python

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, computer-science

I am currently having trouble with a AVL tree in Python 3. I have wrote out the source code that I am following which is on a video, but it is acting strange and I have no idea why.

Here is the code:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, parentNode):
        self.data = data
        self.parentNode = parentNode
        self.rightChild = None
        self.leftChild = None
        self.balance = 0

    def insert(self, data, parentNode):
        if data < self.data:
            if not self.leftChild:
                self.leftChild = Node(data, parentNode)
            else:
                self.leftChild.insert(data, parentNode)
        else:
            if not self.rightChild:
                self.rightChild = Node(data, parentNode)
            else:
                self.rightChild.insert(data, parentNode)

        return parentNode

    def traverseInOrder(self):
        if self.leftChild:
            self.leftChild.traverseInOrder()

        print(self.data)

        if self.rightChild:
            self.rightChild.traverseInOrder()

    def getMax(self):
        if not self.rightChild:
            return self.data
        else:
            return self.rightChild.getMax()

    def getMin(self):
        if not self.leftChild:
            return self.data
        else:
            return self.leftChild.getMin()


class BalancedTree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rootNode = None

    def insert(self, data):

        parentNode = self.rootNode

        if self.rootNode == None:
            parentNode = Node(data, None)
            self.rootNode = parentNode
        else:
            parentNode = self.rootNode.insert(data, self.rootNode)

            self.rebalanceTree(parentNode)

    def rebalanceTree(self, parentNode):
        self.setBalance(parentNode)

        if parentNode.balance < -1:
            if self.height(parentNode.leftChild.leftChild) >= self.height(parentNode.leftChild.rightChild):
                parentNode = self.rotateRight(parentNode)
            else:
                parentNode = self.rotateLeftRight(parentNode)
        elif parentNode.balance > 1:
            if self.height(parentNode.rightChild.rightChild) >= self.height(parentNode.rightChild.leftChild):
                parentNode = self.rotateLeft(parentNode)
            else:
                parentNode = self.rotateRightLeft(parentNode)

        if parentNode.parentNode is not None:
            self.rebalanceTree(parentNode.parentNode)
        else:
            self.rootNode = parentNode

    def rotateLeftRight(self, node):
        print("Rotation left right....")
        node.leftChild = self.rotateLeft(node.leftChild)
        return self.rotateRight(node)

    def rotateRightLeft(self, node):
        print("Rotation right left....")
        node.rightChild = self.rotateRight(node.rightchild)
        return self.rotateLeft(node)

    def rotateLeft(self, node):

        print("Rotate left....")
        b = node.rightChild
        b.parentNode = node.parentNode
        node.rightChild = b.leftChild

        if node.rightChild is not None:
            node.rightChild.parentNode = node

        b.leftChild = node
        node.parentNode = b

        if b.parentNode is not None:
            if b.parentNode.rightChild == node:
                b.parentNode.rightChild = b
            else:
                b.parentNode.leftChild = b

        self.setBalance(node)
        self.setBalance(b)

        return b

    def rotateRight(self, node):
        print("Rotation right....")
        b = node.leftChild
        b.parentNode = node.parentNode

        node.leftChild = b.rightChild

        if node.leftChild is not None:
            node.leftChild.parentNode = node

        b.rightChild = node
        node.parentNode = b

        if b.parentNode is not None:
            if b.parentNode.rightChild == node:
                b.parentNode.rightChild = b
            else:
                b.parentNode.leftChild = b

        self.setBalance(node)
        self.setBalance(b)

        return b

    def setBalance(self, node):
        node.balance = (self.height(node.rightChild) - self.height(node.leftChild))

    def height(self, node):
        if node == None:
            return -1
        else:
            return 1 + max(self.height(node.leftChild), self.height(node.rightChild))
```

As I test this, this is what happens.

I create a  tree:

```
tree = BalancedTree()
```

I then try to insert 3 intergers.

```
tree.insert(4)
tree.insert(2)
```

Now when I enter the third interger.

```
tree.insert(3)
```

I get this output without calling any functions.

> Rotation left right....
>   Rotate left....
>   Rotation right....

That is what happens. I try to traverse the tree. I receive this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       tree.traverseInOrder() AttributeError: 'BalancedTree' object has no attribute 'traverseInOrder'

Yet the video I am following his code works fine. I am lost as I have relooked over the code to see if I made a mistake somewhere and doesn't seem like I have. What am I missing? In his code there is no traverseInOrder function for the tree itself. Yet he is able to call it and run it just fine. Can someone explain why this is happening? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that your indentation is incorrect for the usage you give.  As posted, **class node** consists of only this:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data, parentNode):
    self.data = data
    self.parentNode = parentNode
    self.rightChild = None
    self.leftChild = None
    self.balance = 0
```

Then you have a few independent functions, followed by your trivial **balancedTree** class, and a few other independent functions.

However, this wouldn't allow you to insert a value the way you've done it, so it appears that the posted code is not what produced the output you give.

---

UPDATE

I fixed the indentation.  The code appears to properly insert and balance the tree of 3 nodes.  However, there is no error.  The line of code you cite,

```
tree.traverseInOrder()
```

does not appear in your posted code.  Without accurate code and the *full* error message, including the full traceback, we can't debug your problem.

I also tried adding that line at the bottom of your code, and finally got the error message you cite.  The run-time system is correct (no surprise): there is no **traverseInOrder** method for class BalancedTree.  That name *does* exist for class **Node**, but that's not what you called.  You've confused your two classes.  Sort this out, and the code may well work.

Comment: It is indented correctly or I wouldn't have been able to insert the 4 and the 2. Also I would have noticed a clear indention error.

Comment: khampson's edit fixed your indentation errors.  You needed to make a code block from the entire program.